# How do I integrate the Solana wallet adapter into my website?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I am working on a web based game. And I want to connect Solana wallet to my website. How can I integrate Solana wallet adapter to my website. I've read Githubi but I don't understand where to write the codes or how to run them as I'm new to this stuff. What I want is as in the picture.[image]

Comment: you can reference this dapp scaffold to get an idea of where to start: https://github.com/solana-labs/dapp-scaffold

Comment: How do I run the github folder after downloading it to my computer?

Answer (score 1):

here is a solana game example with an anchor program:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-starter-kits/tree/main/tiny-adventure/app

clone the repository, open it in visual studio code and then go into the folder tiny-adventure/app in the terminal and run

```
yarn install
```

and then

```
yarn dev
```

This will start up the next js client and you can play via wallet adapter.

You may need to install node and yarn
https://nodejs.org/en/download
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable
and maybe solana cli:
https://docs.solana.com/de/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy to follow guide for integrating solana wallet adapter in your dapp.

https://www.solanawalletadapter.xyz/

Hope this helps!